# sequelize.js after insertion to database process doesn't exit/close

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My Models

**`index.js`**

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**`course.js`**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    url: DataTypes.STRING,
    downloaded: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    date_published: DataTypes.DATEONLY
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Course;
};
```

**`test.js`**

```
const Course = require('./models').Course
const courses = [
    {
        title: 'xyz1',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/xyz1'
    },
    {
        title: 'xyz2',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/xyz2'
    }
]


courses.forEach(item => Course.create(item).then(course => {}))
```

> **`My Problem:`** Now when run `node test.js` **it doesn't exit after code**
>   execution.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831493/my-nodejs-script-is-not-exiting-on-its-own-after-successful-execution

Comment: @Praveen This case isn't actually mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are running a script from command line sequelize connection pool isn't closed that's why we need to call the `sequelize.close()`(http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#general) to shutdown the pool on our finished jobs or run `process.exit()` which also will kill the pool.

In node untill all the work is done e.g event listening to something or any `setInterval` or like here any connection open(socket connection) execution will not be finished. That's why the execution wasn't finished here.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code as -

```
const db = require('./models');
const Course = db.Course;

const courses = [
    {
        title: 'xyz1',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/xyz1'
    },
    {
        title: 'xyz2',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/xyz2'
    }
];

function _createCourses(courseList) {
   courseList.forEach(course => {
      Course.create(course).then(createdCourse => {
         console.log(createdCourse.get({
            plain: true
         }));
      });
   });
}

db.sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
     _createCourses(courses);
  });
```

The only difference here is we are calling `sequalize.sync` before creating the model objects. `sync` actually syncs all defined models in db. Check out the documentation for details - [sequalize.sync](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync)