# Node async operations on child_process are not ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, child-process

I have a little script that executes a childprocess using `execFile`. This child process is a node script too that runs `async` operations but it seems like that the `async` are never ending so the terminal and all the processes are on hold.

This is the main script that runs the `execFile` for the child process:

```
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
if (err) console.log(`Error: ${err}`);

files.map((file) => {
    execFile(`node`, ["updater.js", "BMW", file], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            red(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }

        if (stderr) {
            red(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }

        console.log(stdout);
    });
 });
});
```

And this is the node script executed as child process:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const brand = args[0];
const model = args[1];

const data = readJSON(`./json-export/${brand}/${model}`);
const generations = data.generations;

const generationsDB = await getGenerationsByModelAndBrand(brand, model);
console.log(generationsDB);

generations.map((generation) => {
   const lastModification =
       generation.modifications.modification[
           generation.modifications.modification.length - 1
        ];

  console.log(lastModification);
});
```

All the code works if I comment the `const generationsDB` line and the next `console.log`.  If not when execution hits to the `async` request the execution gets stucked there.
Tested the `getGenerationsByModelAndBrand` on the main script and works with no issue.

The `getGenerationsByModelAndBrand` runs a query on database and returns a `Promise`.

This is the `getGenerationsByModelAndBrand` method code:

```
export const getGenerationsByModelAndBrand = (brand, model) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = `DATABASE SELECT`;
        connection.query(sql, function(error, result) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

`connection` comes from `mysql.createConnection` method from the `mysql` package.

I believe that the issue comes from the promise handling on the child process is like I'm missing something bu couldn't find what it is.

Edit:
After researching I didn't found a solution or explanation for this issue therefore in the meantime I moved the `getGenerationsByModelAndBrand` to the parent script and pass the result as parameter.

Comment: There might be situations, where a mysql connection prevents the process from exiting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831493/my-nodejs-script-is-not-exiting-on-its-own-after-successful-execution. BTW if you encounter an error in the callback of `fs.readdir` you should probably stop execution because `files` might be `undefined`

Comment: I'm checking it with help of the `wtfnode` package but if I place the `dump()` method inside the `files.map` I get no response I only get response when I place it outside not sure why. I will keep investigating on this I didn't know this behavior either on the `mysql` package.

Comment: Can you try adding a `return` in front of `connection.query`  and removing the return that is in front of the `reject` and `resolve`?